# how to sort groovy list values based on some criteria

Tags: grails, groovy

I have one scenario to sort the values based domain class property. This property may acept all numeric and alphanumeric values in the format XXX-1.

```
 def res= Book.listOrderByName()
```

or

```
 def res = Book.findAll("from Book order by name")
```

Giving the same result and result is displaying first numbers latter alphanumeric values.
My problem is :
these values are sorted before -.
for example i have AB-1,AB-2,...AB-12.

The result is displayed as AB-1,AB-10.AB-11,AB-2,AB-3,..AB-9

I have result like:

```
  [18001,18002,2,300,3901,42,9,AB-1,AB-10,AB-2,AB-21,AB-9]
```

It should display the value as:

```
  [2,9,42,300,3901,18001,18002,AB-1,AB-2,AB-9,AB-10,AB-21]
```

Comment: @Riduidel I suspect he's not a native English speaker, so the rudeness of "please respond immediately" may not be intentional

Answer (score 7):

Run this in the [Groovy console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/):

```
List sort(list) {

  list.sort {a, b ->
    a.class == b.class ? a <=> b : a instanceof Integer ? -1 : 1
  }
}

// Test the sort function
def list = [18001,18002,2,300,3901,42,9,'AB-1','AB-10','AB-2','AB-21','AB-9']
assert sort(list) == [2, 9, 42, 300, 3901, 18001, 18002, 'AB-1', 'AB-10', 'AB-2', 'AB-21', 'AB-9']
```

Comment: I really find you nice with our friend, as you already know he will **never** accept your perfect answer (which in fact only miss a link to a direct web execution service like groovyconsole ... oh oh, an idea for meta)

Comment: Regardless of whether this answer will be accepted or not, I'm certain it will prove to be useful for others with similar problems!

Comment: @Riduidel I've added the Groovy console link. Hopefully your remarks will encourage Odaiah to prove you wrong by accepting my answer

Comment: @don think you need to split the xx-nn elements and sort them based on xx first, then nn as int if the xx is identical. (so that ab-10 > ab-2)

Comment: @tim not sure I follow, but if you can come up with a better/groovier solution, feel free to edit my answer